# Alphanumeric generator with restrictions

Tags: c++, python

I want to create a generator that will use these characters:   B C D F G H J K M P Q R T V W X Y Z     2 3 4 6 7 8 9

I want it to select 18 random letters from the list and 7 random numbers from the list and shuffle them together (total of 25). There can be repeats.  Python or C++. Please Help!

python code attempt:

```
import string
import random
letters = [random.choice('BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXYZ') for x in range(18)]
numbers = [random.choice('2346789') for x in range(7)]
random.shuffle(letters + numbers)
```

Comment: please post some code showing your attempts.

Comment: Look up `random.choice()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had it almost right:

```
>>> import random
>>> letters = [random.choice('BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXYZ') for x in range(18)]
>>> numbers = [random.choice('2346789') for x in range(7)]
>>> s = letters + numbers
>>> random.shuffle(s)
>>> s
['J', 'P', 'F', 'M', '3', 'Q', 'K', 'P', '2', 'K', '7', 'J', 'B', 'P', 'X', 'G', 'M', 'B', 'K', '9', '9', 'B', '8', 'V', '8']
```

`random.shuffle(letters+numbers)` works, sort of, but `shuffle` works in-place and returns `None`.  So you're creating a temporary list, shuffling it, and then losing any reference to it.

BTW, if needed:

```
>>> ''.join(s)
'JPFM3QKP2K7JBPXGMBK99B8V8'
```

Comment: What if I want to remove the brackets and apostrophes automatically?

Comment: @ShadowWesley77: I don't know what you mean.  There are no brackets and apostrophes in the list, that's just what the representation of a list of strings looks like.  If you want to combine the list into one string, then that's what my final example is for: `''.join(s)` turns a list of strings into one string, by joining them putting `''` between them.

Comment: Shouldv've known that.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a way to add dashes after every 5 characters?

Comment: @ShadowWesley77: that's really more a separate question.  That said, sure: if `s` is a list, you can do something like `'-'.join(''.join(s[5*i:5*(i+1)]) for i in range(len(s)//5))`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, at least, put them in an array, and loop 18 times, get a random element with `data[rand()%length]`, where length is the length of the array, check if it is a character, and put it into a destination or loop again. Then, loop again, but this time check if it is a character, and put it into a destination.

An example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    const int length=25;
    char data[]={'B', 'C', /* ... */};
    for(int i=0; i<18; ++i)
    {
           for(char c=data[rand()%length+1];!isalpha(c);); // loop until c is char
           cout << c;
    }
    for(int j=0; j<7; ++j)
    {
           for(char c=data[rand()%length+1];!isdigit(c););
           cout << c;
    }
}
```